# Use the value of a variable in a function

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Edit : 
My first question was closed and linked to : [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)
but I dont think this resolve my problem :

Initial post :

> kinda new to angular and typescript, I'm strugling with something
>   without finding the correct answer.  I want to use the value of a
>   variable in some functions/directives, this is vague so let's illustrate with an
>   exemple:
>
> Lets take a simple setter function for an angular form where a click
>   on a button call a setter for an input.
>
> ```
> setInput1(value){
>     this.myForm.controls.inputName1.setValue(value);
>   };
> ```
>
> My question is simple, if I have multiple inputs, instead of creating
>   multiple functions like bellow:
>
> ```
> setInput1(value){
>         this.myForm.controls.inputName1.setValue(value);
>       };
> setInput2(value){
>         this.myForm.controls.inputName2.setValue(value);
>       };
> setInput3(value){
>         this.myForm.controls.inputName3.setValue(value);
>       };
> ```
>
> Can I use **the value of a variable** {inputName} inside my function:directive
>   in some way, like below ?
>
> ```
> setInputs(value, inputName){
>         this.myForm.controls.{inputName}.setValue(value);
>       };
> ```

Corrections after reading the link and some more html, using the setValue() method of angular FormControl for the sake of explanations :

**html :**

```
<label>random input name 1
        <input type="number" formControlName="inputName1" class="form-input"> 
</label>

<label>random input name 2
         <input type="number" formControlName="inputName2" class="form-input"> 
</label>

<label>random input name 3
            <input type="number" formControlName="inputName3" class="form-input"> 
</label>
```

***TypeScript :***

```
 mySetValue(btnValue){
    let inputRandom :any = {name : 'inputName1'};

    this.myForm.controls.inputRandom[name].setValue(btnValue);
  };
```

Using the bracket, does not work either.
It seems typescript doesnt interprete it like I want to because I want this :

```
this.myForm.controls.inputRandom[name].setValue(btnValue);
```

to be interpret as :

```
 this.myForm.controls.inputName1.setValue(btnValue);
```

Please, can someone be more specific if I'm wrong in understanding what was linked to me ?

Comment: what about `this.myForm.controls.[inputName].setValue(value);`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: use a property accessor

Comment: try this.myForm.get(inputName).setValue(value)
the function get(controlName) return the control with the required name

Comment: I tried all your method, I know how to use a property accessor but the problem is that  it seems that type script doesnt interpret that way..

Comment: TypeScript has nothing to do with it. You're just placing the brackets wrong. `this.myForm.controls[inputRandom.name].setValue(...)`!

Comment: Many thanks @deceze it works, last thing, should I always acces the propertie of an object, or can I do the same with a simple variable like foo = "myVariableValue"

Comment: Are you talking about [*variable variables*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5187530/476)? Those are virtually always a bad idea.